# Obtaining distribution from histogram

Tags: distributions, matlab, histogram

I have an array of values, with those values I plotted the histogram, calculated mean and variance. I want to know the corresponding distribution from the histogram obtained. How is it possible? Could you please explain the steps in obtaining appropriate probability distribution from histograms?

Comment: What do you mean by "obtaining distribution from histogram"?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I fully understand the question.  If you are interested to know which distribution best fits your data then I would direct you to this QnA which gives a very good detailed answer ([How to determine which distribution fits my data best?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/132652/how-to-determine-which-distribution-fits-my-data-best))

Answer (score 1):

To find candidates for the distribution by histogram, you will need to know the look of a range of distributions in their respective histogram. If there is a bunch of data points in the middle and decreasing to the right and the left of that in a symmetric way, than normal Distribution is a good candidate. 
If it has a big bunch of data in one place and less to both sides but with a long tail to the right, then lognormal distribution is a candidate. If there is a distinct window of values with a limit to the right and a limit to the left, then beta distributions should be considered:

Take some time with the Wikipedia and study the probabily distribution of a number of distributions:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-distribution
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)

Once you have identified a candidate then quantile-quantile plots are often advantageous over histograms to check the fit:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q%E2%80%93Q_plot
They just need more getting used to.