# What to do if no probability distribution accurately represents my data?

Tags: r, distributions, fitting

I am trying to find what distribution would fit logarithmic stock returns. I already did a Jarque Bera test with my data and got a p value smaller than .05

```
library("TTR") 
library("tseries")   
sign="^GSPC"
start=20150101
end=20160101
x <- getYahooData(sign, start = start, end = end, freq = "daily")
x$logret <- log(x$Close) - lag(log(x$Close))
x<-x[,6]
jarque.bera.test(as.numeric(na.omit(x)))

Jarque Bera Test

data:  as.numeric(na.omit(x))
X-squared = 637.01, df = 2, p-value < 2.2e-16
```

I also tried to look for some possible candidate solutions from [How to determine which distribution fits my data best?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/132652/how-to-determine-which-distribution-fits-my-data-best) with the Cullen and Frey graph

```
library("fitdistrplus")
descdist(as.numeric(na.omit(x)), discrete = FALSE)
```

[image: Cullen and Frey Graph]

So apparently no distribution is a good candidate for the data I am using. What is the step to follow?

EDIT: Here is an histogram of my data

[image]

Comment: Switch to [non-parametric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonparametric_statistics) or empircal methods?

Comment: Could you post histogram or density plot of your data? What do you know about it? In most cases you do not find distributions by exhaustive search and testing but rather assume one that nicely approximate your data. Btw have you seen: http://finance.martinsewell.com/stylized-facts/scaling/Officer1972.pdf

Comment: What is your goal? Why do you need to fit a distribution to your data?

Comment: I want to use a Hidden Markov Model to predict future stock returns @Roland

Comment: Here is the code of the HMM http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39537659/simulate-markov-chain-with-probabilities-matrix-as-s4-object-in-r @Roland

Comment: I´m new to non-parametric methods. Would you mind to share a good source to start applying them? @KeithHughitt

Comment: You have a hug sample size, so perhaps it is not surprising that just about any distribution can be shown to at least misfit a little bit, but is the non-fit relevant or would the predictions still be pretty good with e.g. a normal or t-distribution?

Comment: The predictions were pretty good, from time to time stock prices behave completely random hence they become unpredictable. Nonetheless, I think the predictions would improve if they were made on the right distribution. I have tried them with normal distribution but not with t-distribution. Problem is I don´t know how to make goodness of fit for t distributions @Björn

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/132700/11849

Comment: Given any dataset, no matter how large, there are infinitely many distributions that will fit it.  The comments suggest your real problem is nothing like the question you have posted.  It might be better to start over with a more suitable question.

Comment: @whuber I don't know how to make goodness of fit for t distribution, that being said, that is not my main concern. The reason why I posted this is because I want to know what should I do if no distribution fits in my data. What do you mean by "there are infinitely many distributions that will fit"? How do I apply that on my data?

Comment: Trying to fit some distribution to your data sounds like an unconstructive approach to whatever it is you're trying to do.  Given *any* dataset, anyone can find a distribution that will fit it *perfectly.*  But the exercise is pointless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Cullen and Frey graph clearly suggests a distribution with low skewness (consistent with symmetry, for example) and high kurtosis.

The diagram unfortunately doesn't tell you any, but that doesn't mean there aren't any!

There's an infinite number of distributions with those properties, but if you're after a distribution in the Pearson family (which is what using such a graph would tend to suggest you're after) that would suggest a t-distribution

[image: Pearson plot/Cullen & Frey plot indicating value near the t-line]

-- the point is very close to the t-line (Pearson type VII; the green half-line running from the $N$ to the right of the plot). Note that this plot is flipped around compared to the Cullen and Frey plot; your plot's t-line runs down the page.

(Specifically, this would be a t distribution with three parameters - df, location and scale), though among the Pearson family it could as easily be a Pearson type IV (one close to t in appearance but not actually perfectly symmetric),

As it happens, using $t$ distributions to model log-returns is very common.

[However there are often difficulties in estimating degrees of freedom, location and scale simultaneously.]

The suggestion from the kurtosis value is something in the rough ballpark of 4.7 df but simulation suggests that sampling from t-distributions (even with n over 6000) will frequently turn up a kurtosis of about that size for degrees of freedom from somewhat below 6 down to well below 4$^\dagger$; 5 is quite consistent with it, as is 3.5.

Note however, that simple distributions are models (i.e. approximate descriptions) not exact. If you have a large enough sample size (and a suitable test*) you'll always reject some simple distributional model *even if it's a really good approximation* and entirely suitable as a model. With larger and larger sample sizes you can detect what are essentially trivial differences from the model.

To actually assess whether your model is reasonably accurate I would suggest neither a goodness of fit test nor a histogram (though if you add a lot more bins it might not be so bad) - I'd suggest looking at a Q-Q plot or a P-P plot instead.

$\dagger$ even though 4df implies infinite population kurtosis, the modal sample kurtosis for 4 df and n=6000 is still below 10)

* The Jarque Bera would not identify deviations in distribution that aren't reflected in skewness and kurtosis. Very different distributions can have the same skewness and kurtosis. It lacks power against alternatives that don't differ on at least one of the two.

Answer (score 3):

This is a widely studied problem in quantitative finance. You've selected and posted only one year worth of data. If your time series was extended back to 2007, you would see ever greater divergence in your chart with the inclusion of the market crashes back then.

Returns are well known not to be normal, log normal or even t-distributed. All three distributions show significant lack of fit vis-a-vis returns. There's the famous story, perhaps told best by David Hand in his book *The Improbability Principle* (p. 147), of the Goldman-Sachs CFO who testified in Congress after 2007 that, based on the normal distribution, the recent financial shocks were "25-standard-deviation events, several days in a row." The fact is that, based on the normal, there isn't enough time in the history of the *universe* to capture a 1 in 25-sigma event probability. Thus, it's no surprise that the Jacques-Bera would reject an assumption of normality...but then, the J-B rejects normality almost every time it's applied.

Hand goes on to note, "If the distribution of market fluctuations isn't normal, it must have some other shape." His suggestion of a better fit to stock returns is the Cauchy distribution. And he provides a table comparing the normal and the Cauchy in terms of the probabilities of event moves. Based on this table, it's evident that we should expect rare events to occur with much greater frequency:
[image]

As @glen_b notes, Q-Q plots are a sensible way to examine and compare fit or the lack of it. Another approach that is quite useful with extreme valued information is to estimate a tail index. The literature concerned with extreme value theory is quite large and estimands of this index include Hill and Pickand's methods -- both computationally intensive. A more straightforward heuristic is to leverage Gabaix's OLS-based approach using the log of the ranks of the data as described in his paper *Rank - 1/2: A Simple Way to Improve the OLS Estimation of Tail Exponents*. (An ungated copy can be found here: http://www.eco.uc3m.es/temp/jbes.2009.06157.pdf). Gabaix contends that his approach is mathematically well-founded but it's not without controversy. For instance, Shalizi argues in his presentation *So You Think You Have a Power Law Do You?* (an ungated copy can be found here http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/2010-10-18-Meetup.pdf), that OLS estimators of tail exponents are "bad practice." I won't take sides on this, you be the judge.

Once one has estimated a tail exponent, there's a bit of a cheat sheet on this Wiki page about Tweedie Distributions. Look under "Examples," where the magnitude of the index is aligned with possible explanatory, extreme valued distributions (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tweedie_distribution).

One individual who has thought and continues to think deeply about the implications of extreme market moves is Didier Sornette, now Chair of the Financial Crisis Observatory at ETHZ. His 2004 book *Why Stock Markets Crash: Critical Events in Complex Financial Systems* is a superb overview on the manifold complexities in analyzing stock returns. In addition, his ETHZ website has many, many more papers examining a huge many other aspects of these problems. The sophistication of Sornette's views on markets, bubbles and risk more than repays the effort involved in understanding them.

Other useful observers, practitioners and developers of EVT (extreme value theory) include Paul Embrechts, also at ETHZ, whose 1996 book *Modeling Extreme Events* remains a classic and the bible in the field. Then, there's always Nassim Taleb whose free book *Silent Risk* can be downloaded from his website: https://fernandonogueiracosta.files.wordpress.com/2014/07/taleb-nassim-silent-risk.pdf. Taleb can be a bit of a blowhard but his views, while always controversial, are widely cited.

To summarize and answer your query, it is definitely *not* the case that "no distribution summarizes your data." You've been given a variety of tools and resources to tackle this problem in these responses. So, go out and pick a distribution, then motivate it.

Comment: +1.  I'm curious, though, what a "5-sigma" excursion for a Cauchy distribution might be, since "sigma" for a Cauchy distribution is infinite!  (Evidently the table assumes "sigma" is unity--but what that means for the Cauchy distribution is unclear.)

Comment: @whuber Good point. I would be second-guessing David Hand if I attempted to answer you. Having corresponded with him, he is amenable to email. Why not ask him?

Comment: @whuber They (mis-) use SD/sigma for the 'scale' parameter of the Cauchy.  You can check this by verifying that `1 / (1 - pcauchy(5)) ~= 15.9`

Answer (score 1):

Stock return distributions can be well approximated with heavy-tail Lambert W x Gaussian distributions. They are implemented in the [**LambertW** R package](https://github.com/gmgeorg/LambertW) and the [`pylambertw` Python module](https://github.com/gmgeorg/pylambertw).  Advantage of this distribution is that you can "gaussianize" your data based on the estimated distribution parameters (using a bijective trnsformation).

Showing R code examples here, but same can be done in `pylambertw` using `pylambertw.mle.MLE()` sklearn Estimator/Transformer.

**Note:** I downloaded the data directly from Yahoo Finance for the year of 2015 and computed `x = logret * 100` to get daily % change; didn't get exactly the summary statistics you have, but same stylized facts of returns).

Simple normality checks (both visual and hypothesis testing) are in line with your findings:

```
LambertW::test_norm(x)
$seed
[1] 277666

$shapiro.wilk

    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  data.test
W = 0.97609, p-value = 0.0003105


$shapiro.francia

    Shapiro-Francia normality test

data:  data.test
W = 0.97193, p-value = 0.0001607


$anderson.darling

    Anderson-Darling normality test

data:  data
A = 1.4285, p-value = 0.001062
```

[image: norm test original data]

The daily stock returns show the typical stylized facts of a heavy-tailed distribution.  You can use maximum likelihood estimation (MLE) to fit a Lambert W x Gaussian distribution to this data, in particular the location, scale, and tail parameter $\delta$.

```
mod <- MLE_LambertW(x, distname="normal", type="h")
summary(mod)

Call: MLE_LambertW(y = x, distname = "normal", type = "h")
Estimation method: MLE
Input distribution: normal

 Parameter estimates:
       Estimate  Std. Error  t value Pr(>|t|)    
mu     0.004030    0.056308   0.0716  0.94294    
sigma  0.810480    0.059024  13.7314  < 2e-16 ***
delta  0.114220    0.045662   2.5014  0.01237 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
-------------------------------------------------------------- 

Given these input parameter estimates the moments of the output random variable are 
  (assuming Gaussian input): 
 mu_y = 0; sigma_y = 0.98; skewness = 0; kurtosis = 6.34.
```

In this case the $\hat{\delta} = 0.115$, which means moments up to 1 / 0.115 = 8.6 exist; the implied kurtosis of the underlying data is 6.34 (as a function of $\hat{\delta}$).

After Gaussianization the resulting back-transformed, gaussianized stock return data is indistinguishable from a Normal distribution.

```
x.gauss <- ts(LambertW::get_input(x, mod$tau))
LambertW::test_norm(x.gauss)

$seed
[1] 760417

$shapiro.wilk

    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  data.test
W = 0.99439, p-value = 0.4815


$shapiro.francia

    Shapiro-Francia normality test

data:  data.test
W = 0.99433, p-value = 0.4045


$anderson.darling

    Anderson-Darling normality test

data:  data
A = 0.54611, p-value = 0.1588
```

[image: norm checks for x gauss]

```
descdist(as.numeric(x.gauss), discrete = FALSE)
```

[image: Cullen / Frey graph for gaussianized returns]

To @whuber comment above, just fitting a distribution alone does not solve any problem / answer any question.  Depending on what specific question you have, this will be more or less useful.  Nonetheless you now have a distribution that describes the marginal properties of the sample you have in a way that's indistinguishable from the (latent) Normal distribution. You can use this to answer any question you have about the population of daily returns for SP500 [there might be more efficient ways to answer your questions, but the full distribution allows you to use it downstream in any way/shape/form].