# How to fit probability distribution to multi variate data in ?

Tags: r, distributions, outliers, goodness-of-fit

I have dataset of 250000 points which has 15 features. Each feature takes values from 0 to 100.

So, I want to fit a probability distribution to this dataset to identify outliers like wrong data entry.

For univariate, I could follow this [approach](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/132652/how-to-determine-which-distribution-fits-my-data-best). How to do this for multi variate?

How to measure the goodness of fit? Answer with code are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you deal with multivariate data, there is not that much choice of distributions. You might try the multivariate normal and see it it is a reasonable model for your data. Otherwise, you have the multinomial, but then you hit the curse of dimensionality.

You could arrange your observations in a 15 dimensional contingency table, but notice that even if you reduce your 0 to 100 values to "low" and "high" --which would be terribly rough--, you would still have 2^15 = 32768 cells. If you reduce your values to three levels, "low", "medium", "high", which is still quite rough, you would have 3^15 = 14348907 cells, the vast majority of them empty, since you "only" have 250000 observations. Therefore, an observation alone in a cell would no longer be evidence of it being an outlier.

In short, unless you have some more structure in your data, it is hard to think of a way of detecting outliers.