# How to determine the type of probability distribution for a dataset?

Tags: time-series, distributions, confidence-interval, pareto-distribution, distribution-identification

I have aggregated(total) youtube videos views. I have take log of that views. And calculated autoregressive koefs that can be used for the video views predictibility tests. Let say I have aggregated daily views array for each video.  Koef for each video is calculated as:

koef =  aggregatedViews[60]  / aggregatedViews[30]

This list of koefs for all videos forms target distribution.

Initially, I thought that it will be half-normal but looks like this is not normal. Is this Pareto Type I distribution?

Here is 70 bins histogram:[image: 70 bin histogram]

Comment: Can you add more detail about your question? What is the application, e.g. how will you use the results? From where do these data arise?

Comment: @AdamO Autoregressive koefs for Youtube videos views. Added details.

Comment: @BransDs is the y-axis percent or count? Can you produce a cloglog plot of the frequencies? I don't understand why the 1.8 max is so high. Is the X-axis a count? How can you have a fractional count? Explain how you obtain and transform the data in an adequate way.

Comment: @AdomO I have added odrinary histogram without normalization. Y is freq. X is koef.

Answer (score 3):

> How to determine the type of probability distribution for a dataset?

You can use the `fitdistrplus` package in R. First, you can plot a Cullen AC and Frey graph using the `descdist` function in order to find possible candidates of distributions . Then you can fit the best candidates of distributions to your data using `fitdist`. Now you can test the hypothesis that your data comes from these distributions by performing a Kolmogorov-Smirnov test or an Anderson-Darling test. Finally, you can select a fitted distribution using graphical methods or comparing measures of quality like AIC values.

Here you can find a nice example of this procedure:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/132700/154523

Answer (score 1):

This requires intuition and experimentation.  You should appeal to a [QQ plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q%E2%80%93Q_plot) in order to visually measure your distribution against another.

Here is a sample distribution that looks like it might be normal.  Let's put it on a QQ plot against a true normal distribution.

[image]

The red line represents the normal distribution, and we can see that on the tails, the sample distribution does not conform, therefore we conclude that it is not normal.

[image]

Additionally, if you dont trust your eyes, you can use Scikit-Learn's [normaltest()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.normaltest.html) to quantify the deviation from the normal distribution.

Note: you can scale your test distribution with [StatsModels' qqplot()](http://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.graphics.gofplots.qqplot.html)  when presented with the following QQ plot by playing with the `scale` parameter

[image]

The above QQ plot looks like the following after being scaled

`qqplot(standardized_res, dist=normal, line='s', scale=0.7)`

[image]