# Determining the distribution of data

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, descriptive-statistics, heavy-tailed, distribution-identification

[image: the normal distribution plot for the data (and the rug) and the qqplot]

[image: The scatter plot for the data]

[image: I have no idea how to interpret this cullen & frey Graph]

Hi, I am a student learning financial modelling. I would like some help in determining the distribution of the data given the plots above. I am reluctant to assume normal distribution of the data due to the heavy tails associated with it. The descriptive output is as follows:

```
summary statistics

------
min:  -6.278521   max:  6.278521 
median:  0 
mean:  -0.0001706449 
estimated sd:  0.3364102 
estimated skewness:  -1.695425 
estimated kurtosis:  250.3603 
> kurtosis(data)
[1] 246.7675
```

Comment: Will hist, density plot, ks test give any help insights? Also, check this answer: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/132652/how-to-determine-which-distribution-fits-my-data-best

Comment: I do not seem to see the qq-plot mentioned. I would be more worried about the apparent relationship between variance and index than about normality itself.

Comment: What is "index"? Is it simply arbitrary? What is the variable? Please show the QQ plot that you mentioned. A density plot would also be good. You can also do quantile plots against a variety of theoretical distributions.

Comment: Given the super-long tails, check the [Cauchy distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution)

Comment: It's rarely --if ever-- the case in statistics that one can (or needs) to determine the distribution of the *data*. The objective in statistics is to determine the distribution of the *parameters*.