# Bayesian- How to determine the distribution for likelihood function

Tags: bayesian, likelihood

I have a question about likelihood model. Given I have a set of data, how do i find out what type of distribution is suitable for my likelihood function? (eg. Poisson, exponential etc.)

Comment: This has nothing to do with a Bayesian approach. There are many approaches to fitting a model to a dataset, from picking among standard models to using non-parametrics.

Comment: Hi Xi'an, thank you for your reply. I am quite new to this field. Would you mind to recommend me some tools to fit dataset to appropriate model? :)

Comment: The [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution_fitting) entry on the topic is a good start. And so is [this question on X validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/132652/7224).