# Trying to fit a poisson that's dispersed enough but not too dispersed

Tags: r, distributions, fitting

I'm trying to fit some count data for the number of fish purchased by anglers(grey in the image) with a distribution using optim in R. I've fit both a poisson (red) and negative binomial distribution (blue) but as you can see neither seems to be right. What should my next steps be for getting a better fit?

My graph:

[image]

```
#fit poisson curve to data using optim
minus.logL.s<-function(lambda, dat){
  -sum(dpois(dat,lambda, log=TRUE))}

mle<-optim(par=45,fn=minus.logL.s, method="BFGS",hessian=T,dat=survey.responses.baitusers$fish.per.trip)
mle

#simulate data coming from a poisson distribution of mean 38
simspois<-as.data.frame(rpois(1000, 38)) 
colnames(simspois)<-("simulated_values")

#fit negative binomial curve
minus.logL.nb<-function(pars, dat){
  mu<-pars[1]
  size<-pars[2]
  -sum(dnbinom(dat, mu=mu, size=size,log=TRUE))}

mlenb<-optim(par=c(mu=38,size=1),fn=minus.logL.nb, method="BFGS",hessian=T,dat=survey.responses.baitusers$fish.per.trip)
mlenb

simsnegbin<-as.data.frame(rnbinom(1000,size=4, mu=38))
colnames(simsnegbin)<-("simulated_valuesnb")

#graph both
graph<-ggplot(survey.responses.baitusers)+aes(fish.per.trip)+geom_histogram()+geom_smooth(data=simspois, aes(simulated_values), stat = "count",color="red")+geom_smooth(data=simsnegbin, aes(simulated_valuesnb), stat="count", color="blue")
graph
```

Output from negative binomial fitting:

```
$par
       mu      size 
38.333338  4.107287
```

Output from poisson fitting:

```
$par
[1] 38.33333
```

My data:

```
> survey.responses.baitusers$fish.per.trip
  [1]  15  34  42  38   8  38  21  29  58  29  40  35  33  51  50  40   8  45  44  45  34  57   8  28  63  54  22  44  65  54  54  15  12
 [34]  42  59  40  43  95  80  15  54  19  44  27  53  95  21  38  40  13  25  27  79  38  85  40  33  74  34  77  34  34  33  35  89  34
 [67]  34  37  16  60  17  21  18  37  34  27  30  62  48  35  55  50  23  32  56  34  11  21  34  48  15  34  26  54   8  95   8  58  54
[100]  44  34  47  35  13  21  53  52  52  40  40  33   8  15  15  25  41  63  34  38  87  14  68  58  59  34  55  24  24  35  33  21   8
[133]   8  15  51  48   8  21  39  29  50  54  62  16  54  33  58  22  49  40  30  51  21  19  51  40  34  27  40  45  80  69   8  42  33
[166]  62  40  82  17  14  30  61  45  70  33  33  16  49  32  34  31  31  18  64  33  39  21  56  40  52  71  34  30  27  54   8  64  16
[199]  54 127  13  51  40  33  63  31  30  63  56  57  77  46  64  22  34  50  66  33  34  59  45  16  21  60  58  15  64  29  40  44  29
[232]   8  21  16  72  34  49  57  34  34  15  33  54  40  32  33  95 107  49  64  59  64  37  70  45  16  16  40  19  53  34  39  21  36
[265]  34  17   8  34  51  13  20  34  21  38  36  36  41  34  83  27   8  45  29  34  21  37  44  15  50  25  27   8  27  19  24  40   8
[298]  28  36  24  40  21  70  20  34  21  46  16  20   8  33  34  54  44  77  80  15  34  40  29  48  59  29   8  15  47  45  21  41  23
[331]  34  51  14  40  25  45  64  59 107  21  59  27  56  48  34  45  59  35  30  37  32   8  51  11  48  64  32   8  52  14  20  18   8
[364]  53  52  53  33  34  48  62  34  34   8  46  39  21  33  34  40  49  52  19  24  29  43  19  29  27  46  52  29  51  61  16  17  35
[397]  34  40  25  28  34  42  66  35  49  35  51  66  21  51  45  14  53  22  42  64   8  48  28  66  52  40  29  34  34  41  59  34  52
[430]  16  32  20  35   8   8  21  49  40  33  16  24   8  42  23  63  26  21  33   8  23 112  57   8  46  18  67  34  30  33  40  43  57
[463]  60  33  14  27  44  21  31  30  27  49  57  69  66  22  28  55  11  43
```

Comment: I'd recommend using a dedicated package such as `fitdistrplus` or `gamlss` to fit the distributions. Also, there seems to be an excess at around 34 and I believe it's unlikely that either the Poisson or the negative binomial provide a good fit to the data (though the negative binomial is better than the Poisson). I tried to illustrate a couple of approaches to distribution fitting in [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/132652/how-to-determine-which-distribution-fits-my-data-best/132700#132700).

Comment: Could you describe the purpose of performing such a fit?  Why are there no zeros in your data?

Comment: @whuber I am using this data to develop simulations of movement of live baitfish along the live bait distribution pathway. The number of fish represents the number of bait that fishermen reported that they purchased, and they only answered this question if they indicated that they used live bait, so all answers>0.

Comment: You should not be surprised that 90% of data from POIS(38) lies between 28 and 48;  in R, `qpois(c(.05,.95), 38)` returns 28 and 48.

Comment: Re your title: a Poisson is of fixed dispersion -- the variance is always identical to the mean. If your distribution is overdispersed, it can't be Poisson.

Comment: Because by design there are no zeros, a Poisson distribution is an implausible model.  Have you considered using the empirical distribution?  You have a lot of data, so it should work well unless you have a need to include extremely high values in the simulation.